# Работа с сервером

Tags: sql-server, arduino

Есть задача с помощью Arduino собирать собирать данные с датчиков и пересылать их на сервер для хранения и обработки. С сервером я никогда не работал и очень смутно понимаю, как данные на него передать и обработать. Необходимо написать сайт, который будет храниться на сервере, и, собственно принимать и обрабатывать данные или это что-то иное?
Заранее спасибо всем за ответы.

Comment: Как у вас Arduino соединен с сервером? Если через ethernet shield, например, то лучше на сервере установить какой-нибудь из существующих mqtt брокеров, который уже будет сохранять данные, общение между arduino и сервером будет идти по протоколу mqtt. Если подключение напрямую через Serial, то просто на сервере делаете клиент, который сам данные пишет в базу данных, Arduino в этом случае вообще не будет знать, как именно будут сохраняться данные.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, вам нужно реализовать отправку сообщений на другой сервер.
Вы можете найти информацию [тут](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetServer).

Далее нужно решить как именно вы будете писать информацию в базу.

Вы можете найти всю информацию о TDS [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/b46a581a-39de-4745-b076-ec4dbb7d13ec).
Или использовать [arduino-mssql on Github](https://github.com/mustafakemalgilor/arduino-mssql).

Источник: [Arduino To SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45063576/arduino-to-sql-server)